# Decimal Overflow in DB2

Tags: db2, cobol, mainframe

I am doing the below SQL in DB2V10.

```
select
  SUM (ORD_QTY * IFNULL(SELL_AMT,0) * IFNULL(WGT_QTY,0))
  INTO :WS-VAR FROM TABA with ur;
```

---

```
 ORD_QTY  => INTEGER
 SELL_AMT => DECIMAL(13,4)
 WGT_QTY  => DECIMAL(11,4)
 WS-VAR   => PIC S9(13)V9(4) USAGE COMP-3.
```

I am getting +802 DECIMAL OVERFLOW error.

I am not understanding why exactly I am getting decimal overflow here. Can someone explain me please!

Comment: Here's another link: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.codes/src/tpc/p802.dita . It's very simple, you've calculated a number which is too big.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [numeric result rules](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_numericoperands.dita?lang=en), the resulting precision of `SUM (ORD_QTY * IFNULL(SELL_AMT,0) * IFNULL(WGT_QTY,0))` is `DECIMAL(15,4)`, which can hold a value up to the 10<sup>11</sup> range.

At the same time, the actual result could be in the range of up to 10<sup>10</sup> * 10<sup>9</sup> * 10<sup>7</sup>, which adds up to 10<sup>26</sup>.